# How do I prove the triangle inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks to prove the triangle inequality: for all ${\vec{u}},{\vec{v}} $ $\epsilon$ $\Bbb R $,  $\|{\vec{u}} +  {\vec{v}}\|$ $   
\le$  $\|{\vec{u}} \| + \|{\vec{v}} \|$.

Comment: What is $R$? ${}{}$

Comment: The set of all real numbers. I could not get the symbol.

Comment: I presume $\| \cdot \| $ means the absolute value?

Comment: I think it means the "norm" but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Well, it is the symbol for norm, but you need to say what the norm is. On the real numbers, the 'usual' norm is the absolute value.

Comment: yup. it means the absolute value. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\|x\| = |x|$, then:

We have $u \le \|u\|$, $v \le \|v\|$ hence
$u+v \le \|u \| 
+ \|v\|$.

Similarly, $-u \le \|u\|$, $-v \le \|v\|$ hence
$-(u+v) \le \|u\| + \|v\|$.

Combining gives
$\| u+v\| = |u+v| \le \|u \| + \|v\|$.